# Dockers in different networks communicate using their gateway IP

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have these two simple containers in a fresh installation of Arch Linux (made same test also with Alpine):

**alpine1**:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app1:
    image: alpine:latest
    container_name: alpine1
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: sleep infinity
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    networks:
      dnet:

networks:
  dnet:
    driver: bridge
```

**alpine2**:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app1:
    image: alpine:latest
    container_name: alpine2
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: sleep infinity
    ports:
      - "8002:8002"
    networks:
      dnet:

networks:
  dnet:
    driver: bridge
```

**alpine1_dnet**:

- IP: 172.18.0.2/16
- Gateway: 172.18.0.1

They should be isolated from each other, but if I execute:

`docker exec alpine2 nc -vz 172.18.0.1 8001`

It returns `open`.

While it hangs if I use `alpine1` IP address:
`docker exec alpine2 nc -vz 172.18.0.2 8001`

What am I missing? I was expecting that no communication were possible between the two containers since they are attached to different networks (as specified [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)).

I tried to use the default bridge and the behavior is exactly the same, so it seems that there is no difference between default bridge and user-define bridge.

Answer (score 0):

The address `172.18.0.1` is an address **of your host** (specifically, of the virtual bridge device associated with the `alpine1` docker network), and you have explicitly published container port 8001 as host port 8001.

If you don't want containers in `alpine2` to access services in `alpine1`, don't publish ports for those services on the host. Port publishing means, in general, "I want this service to be accessible from everywhere".

Comment: So I don't get the difference between default bridge and user-defined bridge, they are behaving in the same exact way, no difference at all (but name resolution)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question here: there isn't a big difference between them. Both are virtual interfaces on your host; either ip address can be used to access open ports on your host.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the documentation and I was thinking there was a complete isolation between them (containers attached to different bridge networks), but actually you can reach exposed ports if you use the interface IP address of the bridge network.

Comment: You can reach published ports using *any ip address of your host*. That includes bridge devices associated with Docker networks, actual physical interfaces, etc.

Comment: I think my main misunderstanding was that I didn't realize that docker compose automatically creates a user-defined network under the hood (called as containername_default) and I was not aware of that, so I was quite confused since it was always behaving in same way with no user-defined specified in the compose and with one specified (actually by design)